# How to use a value in WHERE clause from a comma separated string in a MySQL Table?

Tags: mysql

How to get records from a table that contains 24 as DeptID. I've added the table structure. What is the SQL query to get the ID and NAME that contains 24 as DeptID?

```
Users:
------
ID  NAME    DeptID
--- -----   -------
1   balaji  1,136,12,53,48,2,153,45,78,53,10,3,143,53,46,49
2   scott   24,90,120
3   balraj  43,9,24,901
```

Comment: I think your main problem lies in your database design. Something like deptlIDlist (userID, DeptID) with DeptID being a simple int would be easier to work with.

Comment: This question should not be answered because it should not be asked. It's called a relational database for a reason -- MySQL can represent your relations -- so don't attempt to do it yourself by encoding them as some kind of string column.

Comment: Satisfy the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of DB design, then come back to ask a question.

Comment: Codd is probably spinning in his grave u_U

Comment: deptlIDlist (userID, DeptID)  136->12,53,48,24. 153->45,78,53,10. 143->53,46,49. Users(userID,Username) 136->marc 158->steve 180->Muru 153->indra 143->mony.  From these, I want php/mysql code for display usernames who are all having DeptID-53.ie(marc,indra,mony). Please tell me if anyone knows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use **find_in_set** function in MySQL.

```
$deptid="24";
```

QUERY is

```
select * from Users where FIND_IN_SET('$deptid', DeptID);
```

Answer (score 3):

After the last comment from the OP I'll do an answer because it as better formating than comments.
Sincerely, it would do you a lot of good to read some things about relational databases before working with them.

But here is how I think your data should be stored:

- User table : (ID, name, other columns)
- Dept table : (ID, name, other columns)
- UserDept table : (userId, deptId)

Then when you want to get a user's dept ID in one string you can do something like

```
SELECT ID, name,
GROUP_CONCAT(deptId SEPERATOR ", ") AS deptIdList
FROM User
INNER JOIN UserDept 
On UserDept.userId = User.ID
GROUP BY(User.ID)
```

Or if you want all the user from department 53:

```
SELECT ID, name
FROM User
INNER JOIN UserDept
On UserDept.userId = User.ID
Where UserDept.deptId = 53
```

Or maybe all the departments names from the user 10:

```
SELECT ID, name
FROM Dept
INNER JOIN UserDept
On UserDept.deptId = Dept.ID
Where UserDept.userId = 10
```

As you can see, everything becomes simple with a normalized database.